# SQLite and/or Zeos causing crash with win8

Tags: delphi, sqlite, delphi-5

just copying a system (been working for years on win7) over to win8 and everything runs (9 other programs) except the two apps that use SQLite3.  This was built using D5ent and ZEOS 6.6. Can't go to Zeos 7 as it will not compile in D5 and I really do not want to convert this to 2007.

Both crash with "SQL Error: Library routine called out of sequence."

I have no idea what that means or how to fix it. I tried moving he entire thing to a non-restricted, well, less-restricted part of the HDD and still the same error. By less-restricted, I mean out of the "Program Files" Folders.

Any thoughts to get me over this?

Thanks

Comment: We'll need some more information to be able to help. What exactly are trying to do the apps when they crash? Are they connecting to SQLite? Preparing a statement? Doing some DML? On the other hand, if you google for the error message you will see a lot of questions here in SO about that same exception.

Comment: That error is usually generated when you do something like preparing a query before the DB is opened. Have you changed the code at all or are the exes identical to the ones on Windows 7?

Comment: @Andy_D Thanks for the comment, yup, I just copied the entire Folder structure over from win7 to win8 and I get the error trying to run the programs. I do not have D5 on the win8 machine so I can't step through and see where it might be going wrong. It is just nuts that this is happening. I used the SQL Firefox plug in to check the database and it is all OK on win8. Gotta be something win8 is causing Zeos to do it seems. Probably more a MSoft thing than Zeos, at a guess. :)

Comment: I suspect this is not a MSSoft problem, but a problem in how you use it. Did you change the SQLite3 library version? Your SQlite3 error is typical from a wrong use of the library, OR unexpected concurrent access. Did you run FastMM4 in full debug mode in Delphi 5 and your dev machine? Is not your SQLite3 file not access several times at once?

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez See my answer. As I had stated, I had changed nothing. It was a direct copy of the entire Folder structure. When copied to the Truecrypt container, it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here's **AN** answer. It is not **THE** answer to the real underlying problem.

On a wild Hare, I created a 5G Truecrypt container and formatted it NTFS and copied the Folder structure to it and it all works perfectly.

So, while not AN answer, it appears to me that this IS a MSoft problem, or maybe an SQLite3 problem. Suffice to say we can run the system in the Truecrypt container with a short and pithy password.

Just as a double-check, I used an SD card with the Folder structure on it and plugged it into the win8 PC. It ran all of the applications perfectly. The SD card had been formatted NTFS, but not sure if that has anything to do with it or not.

So, win8 will run the apps with SQLIte3 as long as they are not on the win8 C: drive. And, before anyone leaps in with an assumption, the original system was win7 pro and everything was running fine on the win7 C: drive.